# How to abort script if there is no part of an image selected? Photoshop Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, photoshop-script

How to abort script if there is no part of an image selected? Photoshop Javascript

I just need a command as a precondition for script to run at all, just check if there is selection, if no selection then abort script.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was basically answered here, it may not have been obvious.

You can check for a selection using `app.activeDocument.selection.bounds`

Turning it into a function is what you need:

```
// create a variable to hold the outcome of the selection (true/false)
var mySelection = is_selection_active();

Display the results of the function
alert(mySelection);

function is_selection_active()
{
  // use try/catch just in case
  try
  {
    // selectbounds is the four points of the largest area of the selection
    // top, left, bottom, right (if memory serves)
    var selectbounds = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds;

    // display the selection bounds co-ordinates
    alert(selectbounds);

    // if there's a selection return true
    return true;
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    // No selection?? Return false
    return false;
  }
}
}
```